# How to set emacs eshell default face?

Tags: emacs, eshell, emacs-faces

When I'm running eshell (or shell) in emacs, I would like to have the default face be a different font (like Courrier) so that eshell looks more like a "normal" shell.

Looking through the Faces for emacs I see several eshell specific faces (for symlinks, directories, prompt, etc.), but I don't see anything for just the basic default face.

Google returns lots of results about customizing the actions of eshell, but very little about customizing its look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun my-buffer-face-mode-courrier ()
    (interactive)
    (setq buffer-face-mode-face '(:family "Courrier"))
    (buffer-face-mode))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'my-buffer-face-mode-courrier)
```

This example is adapted from: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FacesPerBuffer